# Pourquoi « di » est-il au début de « dimanche » alors qu'il est à la fin des autres jours?

Tags: histoire, orthographe, étymologie

Le *di* de *dimanche* est en début de mot, alors qu'il est à la fin pour les autres jours de la semaine. Pourquoi?

Par contraste, en anglais *day* se trouve à la fin de chaque jour de la semaine. Même chose en néerlandais (*dag*), et, j'imagine, dans d'autres langues.

L'[étymologie de *dimanche*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/dimanche) ne donne pas réellement d'explication à ce sujet, la seule différence que je vois avec [un autre jour](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/jeudi) est que l'un vient du latin « chrétien » (*dies dominicus*) tandis que les autres viendraient du latin « normal ». Est-ce qu'il faut y voir l'explication? La latin a-t-il changé entre-temps?

Comment: While I'm too lazy to go back into etymology books right this minute, I'd say it's quite obvious there is a major difference in origin between weekday naming (that honours planets/pagan gods) and the very Christian (one and only "dominus") *dimanche*. From there, the naming pattern difference seems to make sense. - Interestingly, English has kept the planet reference for Sunday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comme à son habitude, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week-day_names) (en anglais) a une page très fournie qui explore les noms de jours de la semaine dans différentes langues. [Wkitionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aDays_of_the_week) a aussi un tableau sans explications.

Déjà, en hébreu, le jour de repos a un nom particulier : dimanche est le « premier jour », et ainsi de suite jusqu'au vendredi « sixième jour », mais samedi est le « jour de repos ». Bien que l'hébreu n'ait pas été une influence importante lorsque le mot « dimanche » a fait son apparition en français, a pu l'être indirectement. En effet, en latin ecclésiastique, samedi se disait *sabbatum* ; vu [l'étymologie du mot *samedi* en français](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/samedi), la racine viendrait du grec (*Σαμβαθώ* attesté au IV<sup>e</sup> siècle). D'ailleurs beaucoup de langues latines ont conservé une forme particulière pour le samedi (*sabato* en italien, *sabado* en portugais, etc) et c'est plutôt le français qui fait exception à avoir réintroduit le suffixe -di.

Pour en revenir au dimanche, il vient donc comme dans beaucoup de langues latines de *dominicus* ou *Dominica* (le jour du seigneur). La formation particulière du mot marque qu'il ne s'agissait pas d'un jour comme les autres, comme le marquait auparavant la forme du mot désignant le samedi. Quant à la première syllabe, elle ne dérive pas directement de la racine di- pour jour : ce n'est pas di- + -manche mais di- + domanche, devenu dio- puis di- (voir l'étymologie dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dimanche)).

Answer (score 6):

Une réponse est donné dans l'article suivant :
[Le dimanche n’est pas catho !](http://www.lepost.fr/article/2011/01/29/2387701_le-dimanche-n-est-pas-catho.html)
Le mot « dimanche », du latin « *dies dominicus* », proviendrait en fait de « *dominica dies* » :

> Pour les puristes le jour du seigneur n'est pas dies dominicus mais
>   dominica dies, l'inversion de l'épithète, ici dominica, soulignant son
>   importance.

Ainsi, seul ce mot aurait évolué alors que « *Lunæ dies* », « *Martis dies* »… non.

Comment: @Joubarc, c'est les 'suggested edits', il n'y a encore personne qui a le droit de les accepter, donc ça attend qu'un de l'équipe de 'community coordinators' se réveillent...

Comment: @Benjol: non, non, je voulais corriger _l'article_ externe dont parle cynddl. Cela dit, pour les edits... F'x ayant plus de 1000 rep devrait déjà avoir accès aux outils de modération, et tous ceux qui ont plus de 500 peuvent éditer directement (ou, je crois, accepter des edits sur lesquels ils tombent par hasard.)

Comment: Bien que cet article soit en apparence fort érudit, j'aurais quelques réserves sur son "académisme" (sans vouloir être snob, je ne crois pas que *Le Post* représente la quintessence de l'éthique journalistique): il contient plusieurs points assez douteux, voire erronés et présente une *théorie* étymologique, à la fin d'une très longue (et sans rapport, bien qu'intéressante) digression. Je prendrais cette source avec un grain de sel...

Answer (score 3):

Entre le latin d’antan et le français d’aujourd’hui il y a aussi eu le patois. De la campagne d’où je sors (la Corrèze), il n’est pas inhabituel d’entendre les anciens noms des jours:

- Lundi: **dilun**
- Mardi: **dimarç**
- Mercredi: **dimècres**
- Jeudi: **dijoun**
- Vendredi: **divendres**
- Samedi: **dissabde**
- Dimanche: **diumenc**

Ça m’a donc l’air d’être une évolution « récente » de la langue.

Comment: De manière très anecdotique, on peut souligner que le *verlan*, alors qu'il a opéré sa transformation sur une grande partie des mots d'usage courant, a fait un curieux évitement sur les noms de jours, alors même que (je l'apprends en lisant ton intéressante contribution, qdii) cela aurait permis de "retomber" sur une version plus ancienne de ces noms. Ah, les caprices de la langue...

Comment: En fait, ce que vous appelez du patois est en réalité de l'occitan (ou langue d'oc), langue différente du français (ou langue d'oïl), et l'occitan a en effet conservé cet ordre indépendamment de l'évolution en français. À noter toutefois que certains dialectes de la langue d'oïl, comme le picard, connaissent aussi des formes comme « diluns », etc.

Answer (score 1):

Petit rappel : en latin, les noms latins se déclinent se déplacent dans la phrase selon leur fonction.

Ainsi au nominatif comme au vocatif, on avait :
dies Lunae, dies Martis, dies Mercurii, dies Jovis, dies Veneris, dies Saturni et dies Solis.

Le jour du Soleil (resté Sunday en anglais) est devenu le jour du Seigneur et dies Dominicus s'est transformé peu à peu en dimanche.

À part le jour du Seigneur, il était rare que le nom d'un jour soit au nominatif (sujet d'un verbe) ou au vocatif (exemple : Ô toi, jour du Seigneur !)...
Le nom du jour est plus souvent utilisé à l'accusatif ( complément d'objet), soit :
Lunae diem, Martis diem, Mercurii diem, Jovis diem, Veneris diem, Saturni diem.

Le jour de Saturne (resté Saturday en anglais) est devenu le jour du Sabbat, et le Sambati diem du latin tardif a donné notre samedi.

Ça semblerait beaucoup plus logique...

Answer (score 0):

La semaine de sept jours nous vient de la tradition hébraïque: D ieu a créé le monde en six jours et le septième jour, le shabbat, il se reposa. Si l’on en croit les Actes de Apôtres, les premiers Chrétiens se réunissaient le premier jour de la semaine, c’est à dire le jour suivant le shabbat, pour prier. Ce jour a donc été appelé par les Chrétiens “jour du Seigneur”. En hébreu et, curieusement, en portugais, les jour de la semaine sont nommés, non pas à partir de déités païennes, comme dans les autres langues européennes, mais selon leur ordre dans la semaine, à partir du samedi (Shabbat, sábado, respectivement): premier jour, deuxième jour, etc. Bien sûr, en portugais, le samedi est suivi du dimanche (domingo) et on commence la numérotation à partir du lundi: “segunda feira”, soit, deuxième jour de marché.